# Is there anything at a higher level than servlet context

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, ear

Servlet context is per application (or per .WAR). Is there anything that attributes can be stored to, to be available to all applications on a server / within an EAR?

Comment: Just to clarify: you're talking about a wider scope (i.e. greater visibility) as opposed to a higher level of abstraction, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EARs/WARs are usually scoped to themselves but some containers have the notion of "shared libraries" which may offer what you want. Some containers use flat classloaders which means static fields from WAR A can be seen in WAR B. All-in-all I would recommend [system properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for most server wide attributes unless the properties are not so static.

For more dynamic data, the final option I would recommend would be to create a JAR with the needed values and add it to the server's class path. Great care must be taken to ensure thread safety among other issues.

Comment: but what about actual POJOs that can change during runtime?

Comment: Updated my answer to include server-level-jars. This is on the edge of bad practices but it works but might cause more headaches than it solves.

Comment: sounds like quite a hack. -Cmon sun/oracle, a "serverContext" would be nice.

Comment: I agree on with you on both comments there :) Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, no, that's as far as the Servlet specification goes. You can of course look into solutions like JNDI (which is typically used for looking up Connections across multiple web applications) or a distributed data structure provider like [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/).